# css libraries not called with xaringan slides on netlify website

Tags: css, r, blogdown, netlify, xaringan

I've prepared some slides using Yihui Xie's xaringan package and Allison Hill's R-Ladies theme. I used these resources: [here](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#1), [here](https://alison.rbind.io/slides/rladies-demo-slides.html#1), and [here](https://timmastny.rbind.io/blog/embed-slides-knitr-blogdown/).

I've uploaded my slides to my website at https://drmolina.netlify.com/slides/rladiesmunichnewsmarch2018.html#1

However, when I load my website in the browser, it doesn't use the css files included in the `libs` folder. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfhwd.jpg) when it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G1JZ.jpg).

It looks fine locally when I run `xaringan:::inf_mr()`.

This is my yaml header:

```
---
title: "R-Ladies Munich <br/> News"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>Made with xaringan"
author: "Daloha Rodriguez-Molina"
date: "March 2018"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["default", "rladies", "rladies-fonts"]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

The `libs` folder is on the [github repo](https://github.com/darokun/drmolina), but not on the webpage.
Netlify doesn't show any errors when deploying, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpfRy.jpg).

This is my `devtools::session_info('xaringan')`:

```
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.423)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  C                           
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2018-03-08                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source                         
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                 
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                 
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
 glue        1.2.0   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
 graphics  * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 grDevices * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 httpuv      1.3.5   2017-07-04 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 cran (@1.20)                   
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 methods   * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
 Rcpp        0.12.15 2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                 
 rmarkdown   1.9     2018-03-01 cran (@1.9)                    
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                 
 servr       0.8     2017-11-06 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
 stats     * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 stringi     1.1.6   2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
 stringr     1.3.0   2018-02-19 cran (@1.3.0)                  
 tools       3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 utils     * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local                          
 xaringan    0.6.1   2018-03-08 Github (yihui/xaringan@d59fd93)
 xfun        0.1     2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                 
 yaml        2.1.17  2018-02-27 cran (@2.1.17)
```

And my `devtools::session_info('blogdown')`:

```
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.423)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  C                           
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2018-03-08                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 blogdown    0.5     2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 bookdown    0.7     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 glue        1.2.0   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 graphics  * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 grDevices * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 httpuv      1.3.5   2017-07-04 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 cran (@1.20)  
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 methods   * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
 Rcpp        0.12.15 2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 rmarkdown   1.9     2018-03-01 cran (@1.9)   
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 servr       0.8     2017-11-06 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 stats     * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 stringi     1.1.6   2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
 stringr     1.3.0   2018-02-19 cran (@1.3.0) 
 tinytex     0.3     2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 tools       3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 utils     * 3.4.3   2017-12-07 local         
 xfun        0.1     2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 yaml        2.1.17  2018-02-27 cran (@2.1.17)
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you CSS files were used. It is just that Netlify bundled all your CSS files into a single one by default (you can disable CSS bundling in your site settings):

[image: asset optimization]

Comment: Thanks! I disabled the bundle function for css on Netlify and now it works (:

Comment: @darokun Please don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: I clicked the check mark and it looks green now. Not sure if that's how to accept the answer (super n00b here at SO)

Comment: @darokun Good job. That's it!